# Как с помощью регулярного выражения заменить код в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: регулярные-выражения, visual-studio-2017

Есть огромное количество кода. Во многих местах есть такие методы:

```
public void GetAccess(Person.prefixProperty prop)
{
  ////
}
```

Хочу заменить это на

```
public void GetAccess(Person.Property prop)
{
   ///
}
```

То есть во всех методах хочу убрать только 'prefix'. Как это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения?

**EDIT**:
Вместо `Person`, `Property` и `prop` могут быть разные переменные и классы

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/KYzWy6/1

Comment: @justcvb, Как исполнит его на Visual Studio ?

Comment: @justcvb, К стати, он не убират 'prefix' когда public void GetAccess(Person.prefixProperty2 prefix)
{
  ////
}

Comment: @justcvb, О пять не работает в public void GetAccess(Person.prefixProperty prefix2)
{
  ////
}

Comment: И в: public void GetAccess(Person2.prefixProperty prefix)
{
  ////
}

Comment: Даполнил вопрос

Comment: Я правильно понял, что `prefix` в `public void GetAccess(Person.prefixProperty prefix)` должны быть совпадать? Или же нет?

Comment: @justcvb, Нет, не должен

Comment: @justcvb, убрал не нужный prefix из вопроса

Comment: почему нельзя в регулярное выражение подставить просто prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно зацепиться за нижний и верхний регистры:

https://regex101.com/r/KYzWy6/5

Comment: А как его исполнит в Visual Studio?

Comment: Так разве в Студии при поиске\замене нет возможности активировать использование регулярных выражений?

Comment: Есть, вклчил, а что поставит на Find и что поставит на Replace?

Comment: Кажется нашел $1$3 проавильно ?

Comment: Да. В выражении захватили три группы: `public void GetAccess(Person.`, `prefix` и `Property prop)`. Вторую отбрасываем.